# model output without correlation to input variable

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pca, cross-correlation, controlling-for-a-variable

let's assume that a,b,c,d,t,u,v,w,x,y,z and o are all correlated to one another. I want to make a prediction for outcome variable "o".  However, I don't want my prediction to be to correlated to variables t,u,v,w,x,y, or z.
I can't simply limit my model to only use a,b,c,d as inputs because the correlation between the variables would still cause my prediction of o  to be correlated to t,u,v,w,x,y,z.

What I need is a function that transforms a variable to remove any correlation to a different set of variables.

for example f(a;t,u,v,w,x,y,z) would produce a' such that a' is not correlated to t,u,v,w,x,y,z.   I realize that a' would be an inferior predictor of o than "a" and I am ok with that.

I would like this solution to work with both continuous and categorical variables for a,b,c,d,t,u,v,w,x,y,z and o.  I would also like the solution to work for larger numbers of variables.
I am open to both statistical and machine learning solutions
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just predict $\bar o$, regardless of $a,b,c,d?$ Then you're definitely uncorrelated with your $t,u,v,w,x,y,z$ variables.

Comment: It sounds like you wish to [control for covariates in a multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=control+covariates+multiple+regression+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5).  Would that be the case?

Comment: @dave, let's assume the only variables i have available to use are a,b,c,d,t,u,v,w,x,y,z and o

Comment: You only need $o$ to calculate $\bar o$ (mean of $o$).

Comment: @whuber  thanks, that is similar to what I am looking for.  a few key things, I don't just want to be able to describe the relationship between o and a,b,c,d after removing the effect of t,u,v,w,x,y,z.  I want to actually be able to assign a score to every row in a dataset with a prediction of o but want that prediction of o to be uncorrelated to t,u,v,w,x,y, and z.   Is there a technique you know of to do this?

Comment: That's precisely what "controlling for" a variable turns out to do.  Another way to achieve the same end (I believe) is to make your predictions, then fit those predicted values using ordinary least squares with explanatory variables $t\ldots z$ (along with a constant term), and take the residuals from that model as your final predictions.  This process guarantees lack of correlation.  Moreover, it works no matter how you constructed the original predictions--you could use a Ouija board or ask your six-year-old neighbor and it would still give uncorrelated predictions :-).

Comment: @whuber  Thanks so much for your help. This is what I was looking for.